# how to store while loop data in string variable and then use it in mail function in php

Tags: php, html, variables, echo

Now,its not printing anything in mail ,i know i have to store loop output to some string variable and then pass it as $message in  mail function.

this code will be then created as php function and used for different mail recipients for sending mails.

```
 <?php
        include db.php;

        $b ="select cnt,Bookings from table";

        $result=mysqli_query($dbconn,$b);

        echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr style= 'background-color:blue'>
        <th style= 'color:white'>cnt</th>
        <th style= 'color:white'>Bookings</th>
        </tr>";

        while (mysqli_more_results($dbconn)) {

            if ($result = mysqli_store_result($dbconn)) {

                 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                            echo "\n<tr>";
                            echo "\n<td>" . $row["cnt"] . "\n</td>";
                            echo "\n<td>" . $row["Bookings"] . "\n</td>"; 
                            echo "\n</tr>";
                      }
                      mysqli_free_result($result);
               }
               mysqli_next_result($dbconn);
        }
        echo "</table>";

        $subject = '';
        $message = $result;

        $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
        mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use concatenation `.` operator, like this

```
 $html = '<!doctype html>
     <html> 
     <head></head>
     <body>
     <table border="1">
      <tr style= "background-color:blue">
       <th style= "color:white">cnt</th>
       <th style= "color:white">Bookings</th>
     </tr> '; 
    $b ="select cnt,Bookings from table";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbconn,$b);
    while (mysqli_more_results($dbconn)) { 
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($dbconn)) { 
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                    $html .= '<tr>';
                    $html .= '<td>'. $row["cnt"] .'</td>';
                    $html .= '<td>'. $row["Bookings"] . '</td>'; 
                    $html .= '</tr>';
              }
              mysqli_free_result($result);
         }
         mysqli_next_result($dbconn);
    } 
    $html .='</table> </body></html>';
    $message = $html;
```

Comment: check your  `select` query and print `$row` variable.

Comment: I have updated my answer check it now. Why you are using two `while` loops ?